# Merge two lists of data.frames

Tags: r

I have two lists of data.frames, called `df_epi_in_strata` and `assign_zeros`:

```
> class(df_epi_in_strata)
[1] "list"
> class(df_epi_in_strata[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"

> df_epi_in_strata[[1]]
   Var1 Freq
1     1    2
2     2    1
3     3    1
4     6    3

> class(assign_zeros)
[1] "list"
> class(assign_zeros[[1]])
> [1] "data.frame"
> assign_zeros[[1]]
      x 0
1     4 0
2     5 0
```

I would like to merge the data.frames such that each list is 'complete', for each list in the data frame. I need to match the list elements. That is, such that the result looks like this, for each of the nine lists in the data frames:

```
result_list[[1]]
  Var1 Freq
1  1   2
2  2   1
3  3   1
4  4   0
5  5   0
6  6   3
```

So I'm merging `df_epi_in_strata[[1]]` with `assign_zeros[[1]]`, `df_epi_in_strata[[2]]` with `assign_zeros[[2]]`, etc.

My plan was to concatenate each set of two data.frames, then sort by column 1. I know I need the names of `assign_zeros` to match the names of `df_epi_in_strata` in order to concatenate the lists.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648513/changing-column-names-in-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r), and set `colnames <- c("Var1", "Freq1")`, but got:

`Error in list2env(lapply(assign_zeros, setNames, colnames), .GlobalEnv) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`

Does anyone know how to merge the data frames by index, getting a result like `result_list` for each of my nine lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s very unclear what you’re actually doing but if you split your problem into parts it’s fairly easy.

First step: create a function that merges *one pair* of data.frames (this is using dplyr because there’s no reason not to):

```
insert_missing_values = function (df, missing) {
    colnames(missing) = colnames(df)
    bind_rows(df, missing) %>% arrange(Var1)
}
```

Next, apply across all pairs of lists:

```
result_list = mapply(insert_missing_values, df_epi_in_strata, assign_zeros)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error: `Error in (function (df, missing)  : could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: @StatsSorceress Like I said, this requires the dplyr package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `purrr` solution with `setNames` to align column names before appending:

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(df_epi_in_strata, assign_zeros, ~rbind(.x, setNames(.y, names(.x))))
```