# How to rename columns in a list of data tables according to a rule?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like some help with the following, have searched around for answers on here (e.g. [Changing Column Names in a List of Data Frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648513/changing-column-names-in-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r)) but cannot find an answer.

I have a list of data tables with unequal numbers of columns like:

```
> set.seed(100)
> 
> # Create tables
> 
> dt1 = data.table(
+   a_a = sample(1:100,5),
+   a_b = sample(1:100,5),
+   a_c = sample(1:100,5)
+ )
> 
> dt2 = data.table(
+   b_b = sample(1:100,5),
+   b_a = sample(1:100,5),
+   b_d = sample(1:100,5),
+   b_g = sample(1:100,5),
+   b_h = sample(1:100,5)
+ )
> 
> dt3 = data.table(
+   c_b = sample(1:100,5),
+   c_d = sample(1:100,5)
+ )
> 
> # List tables 
> my_list <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)
> 
> print(my_list)
[[1]]
   a_a a_b a_c
1:  74  70   7
2:  89   4  55
3:  78  55  43
4:  23 100  82
5:  86   7  61

[[2]]
   b_b b_a b_d b_g b_h
1:  12  25  52  39  93
2:  99   2  48  16  45
3:  51  51  32  75  30
4:  72  68  85  66  98
5:  18  97  91  70 100

[[3]]
   c_b c_d
1:  87  92
2:  95  31
3:  97  54
4:  99  41
5:  29  97
```

What I require is that each of the column names within the list are changed such that the letter_ are removed (using something like `colnames(x) <- sub(".*?_", "", colnames(x))`), such that the new list would look like:

```
[[1]]
    a  b  c
1: 24  9  3
2: 43 20 36
3:  7 14 27
4: 63 78 46
5: 65 88 59

[[2]]
    b  a  d  g   h
1: 46 68 22 44  42
2: 69 12 82 85  15
3: 47 51 53 28  57
4: 55 16  3 52 100
5: 98 56  5 25  76

[[3]]
    b  d
1: 37 55
2: 26 75
3: 24 63
4: 12 35
5:  9 58
```

Basically what I need is instructions how to clean the list names in the way that I have specified above.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Use `lapply` i.e. `lapply(my_list, function(dt) setnames(dt, sub(".*?_", "", colnames(dt))))`

Comment: @akrun You are a veteran on SO and am genuinely thankful for your answers (for both growing the community and my learning). However, why do you sometimes (such as with this question) choose to comment other than post as answer? Because from the home page this makes it seem a good no. of questions are unanswered

Comment: @akrun Understood. The nuances of the system. Thanks too